# How to take mysql dump of selected columns of a table

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I have a requirement in which I have to take mysql dump of just one column of a table. Since that table has too many columns, I don't want to take dump of the full table. I have to get this dump of the table from one server to another. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Mysqldump does not support to export selected columns. Only you can dump full table or selected rows form it. But you can create a view & dump the view. But it is a view not a table.

Comment: Mysqldmp does not work on a view

Answer (score 20):

If you would like to take mysql dump including the schema, it can be done by following the below steps:

create a temp table:

```
create table temp_table like name_of_the_original_table;
```

duplicating data into temp_table:

```
insert into temp_table select * from name_of_the_original_table;
```

dropping unnecessary fields:

```
alter table temp_table drop column somecolumn;
```

post this, you could take a mysqldump by running:

```
mysqldump -u <username> -p <password> databasename temp_table
```

If the intention is to take a data dump(without the schema), you can run the below command:

```
select * from sometable into outfile '/tmp/datadump' fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n';
```

Comment: If you've got a lot of rows in your source table, make sure you drop columns from the target table *before* populating the target table.

Comment: can you dump all the data on the temp table with 1 or more column missing?
like if table1 has 3 columns and temp_table1 has 2 columns, can you still dump the data?

Comment: how about if you duplicate certain columns only from database1 to database2?

Answer (score 9):

Select the column into a file ?

```
Select col from table into outfile 'fileame'
```

Comment: I have to get this dump from one server to another, so this file wouldn't be accessible over there.

Comment: You copy the file, just like you would with `mysqldump`.

Comment: What are you going to with the file on the remove server ?

Answer (score 9):

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `tempTable` AS SELECT `columnYouWant` from `table`;
$> mysqldump yourDB tempTable > temp.sql
```

copy temp.sql to target server, then on target server

```
$> mysql yourDB < temp.sql
mysql> RENAME TABLE `table` TO `tableBackup`, `tempTable` TO `table`;
```

Answer (score 0):

For `The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option`

```
Your MySQL connection id is 86774
Server version: 5.7.41 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Run

```sql
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                 |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| secure_file_priv | /var/lib/mysql-files/ |
+------------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then dump selected column:

```sql
mysql> select user_id from user into outfile '/var/lib/mysql-files/uuu1.txt';
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```